# AVAudioSession, AirPods, and outputLatency accuracy

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm working on an app that needs to synchronize audio output with events on the screen and with very high accuracy (<3 ms). (Imagine a "tap tap revenge"-like game…)

From experience I know there's a fair bit of latency when playing through AirPods (or any BT headset), but when I connect `AVAudioSession` to an AirPods input, the reported `outputLatency` is only 10ms. I haven't thoroughly tested, but this seems like it's on the low side. Does anyone know how accurate `AVAudioSession.inputLatency` and `AVAudioSession.outputLatency` are supposed to be?

```
(lldb) po audioSession.outputLatency
0.009999999776482582

(lldb) po audioSession.inputLatency
0.009999999776482582
```

Comment: Can you expand on the synchronisation part? If your inputs are timestamped then latency doesn't really matter, so I assume you need some kind of realtime synchronisation with the audio input? Anecdotally IIRC bluetooth audio input is ~250ms

Comment: Sorry Rhythmic, I botched the question. I actually meant to refer to output, not input. Obviously on input I have the input timestamps as you said. But with output I need to know when the user actually hears the sound that was played and this is where I'm stuck. I updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: The reported `outputLatency` can't be right. You can device experiments to measure the latency yourself, but just playing with the volume with AirPods/BT will give you an idea of how responsive your game will be. It's not great, but people can learn to deal with lag: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/30455